# How would you describe this hair?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Alright, so this is a pretty pervasive style in modern CGI characters now:

[image]

Colloquially I'd refer to it as "anime hair but real" but anyone who isn't familiar with anime won't even know what that means (plus it's still animated) and I'd like a definition that can stand on its own. What sort of adjectives could I use to describe it? Spiky implies something more punk; it's kinda feathery but calling that would confuse it with the feathered hair fad of the 70s; it's too neat to be shaggy, and as for beyond that, I'll shamelessly admit I'm not proficient with hair. Is there an actual name for this style?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hair and CGI.

Comment: she's looking for a word...that's as close to english usage as one might get. Yet i fear she won't find many answers (i hope to be proven wrong).

Comment: @Matthaeus - no, this is **not** "as close to english usage as one might get." This is a question about *hair*, rendered in CGI, *that happens to be in English*. Not every question in English is *about* English!

Comment: This is a fair question...I doubt that you will find a suitable answer, though.  There are certain kinds of concepts that cannot be succinctly described. e.g., what does an orange taste like? An orange can be acidic, sweet, sour, juicy, pulpy, etc. but a one word/phrase description that would suggest an orange and only an orange is unlikely.  I fear that is likely true here.  Many kinds of hair are 'tousled.'  The best you may get is a awkward indirect description like "Lisa Simpson hair, but floppy"

Comment: @merk "Orangey".

Comment: @Elliott Frisch - you've inadvertently proved my point.  There are lots of other fruits than just oranges that are orangey (kumquats, tangerines, etc.), just as there are many blues and yellows and browns that are greenish.

Comment: @merk did you know the color comes from the fruit? That's why gingers are described as redheads.

Comment: No medica, it is not off topic. I am asking how to **describe** it, in **words**, not how to render it  nor how to cut hair that way. Word requests are a valid question for this site.

Comment: @BBON - Please read the help section about "What kind of questions are on topic here." After you have done that, then back up this claim. While word requests are common on this site, they are **not** always On Topic.

Comment: Perhaps, there's a grooming/ fashion Q&A on SE. I'm not sure.

Comment: This question is not about the English language. It may even turn out that there *is* a word for it, and probably not an English word, for that matter.

Comment: "anyone who isn't familiar with anime ..." that concept is **ridiculous**. Every English speaker knows what anime is.  It would be as if you said people "may not get a reference to Disney or Coke, so you're looking for another term".

Comment: IMO, that hair appears "tousled and unkempt".  If that's the style the anime character was going for, then you can add "intentionally" to the description.

Comment: Isn't it the 'Oxford Apostrophe'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tousled.

Originally a negative meaning, tousled hair or tousled good looks has become a positive way of referring to this kind of slightly unkempt but stylish hair.

Comment: I think he means more the clumped nature than the tousled nature.

Comment: This is completely wrong, no offense.  It's anime hair, CGI hair, video game hair, pixar hair, game character hair or 3D hair.  It's bizarre and freaky this question is causing so much trouble.  The answer is, for goodness sake, "anime hair".

Answer (score 1):

If you said **Emo-style** hair, that's what I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this sort of matted, rumpled , untidy hair style  which is quite popular among young people is called [out of bed](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TaQPmPRnhIU) style.

Answer (score 0):

It's **anime hair**, it's that simple.

**Within the context of internal discussion by professional CGI hair stylers**, they very simply use **the exact same terms "we" would use for haircuts**.

(So, 70s, disco, like Hatsune Miko, long, short, tousled, like James Dean, bangs, Barbie-style, beehive, crew-cut, whatever.)

It's that simple.

You will be amazed when I tell you, I was in fact just recently was party to a conversation by such professionals!  :)

---

**Note** it's worth noting that the technology has moved on far, far beyond this.

At pixar, today, a conversation might go like "we want incredibly old-fashioned anime hair, like from 2010 - four generations of technology ago!"  "Wow, you mean real anime hair?  man that is old old school"

indeed, note that the (amazing) hair in for example Frozen deliberately has a just-slightly anime hair look.

typical site where you can buy hair,

http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-model/anatomy/hair

Answer (score 0):

Anime or emo. The top layers of my hair is somewhat like that. People always tell me my hair is emo or that of an anime character, I agree.