# Is there a more concise way to describe this hairstyle?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

Is there a more concise way to describe this character's hairstyle, other than 'a bun, with parted bangs and tassels framing her face'?

[image: Tear from Recettear]

Comment: The long pieces hanging on either side of her face are termed *pigtails*. The pieces covering her forehead are *bangs*. The bun is, as you said, a *bun*. There is no single word encompassing all these elements (because this is not a common hairstyle; I don't know if it's ever been worn by a real woman, at least not in the West). You'll have to resort to describing them each.

Comment: Say Dan - I've always wondered if pigtails are only at the **back**?!  If you google pigtails for instance, you only get the back ones or the "fluffy side ones" - not these tassle-style front things.

Comment: Consider, it is very possible there is a specific word, in Japan, for precisely this particular character hairstyle.  For all I know, this could be one of the most popular current **cosplay** setups, and as such it could well be that any, what's the term .. desu ..would instantly point out that it is a blah-blah-iko hairdo.  Regarding women wearing it, when you say "not in the west" true but if you wander Akihabara it's commonplace for girls to wear impossible styles like this (just using inserts and wigs)

Comment: @JoeBlow - How is her hair impossible? The metal tassel-things could be held in place by the friction of her hair, and the cloth is holding her bun together. ...... In other news, do you think a question about how to describe her clothes is an acceptable question?

Comment: **pigtail** *noun*: 1. a braid or gathered hank of hair hanging from the back of the head, or either of a pair at the sides.

Comment: Hi Malandy!  You sometimes use the word impossible in a figurative way to mean, sort of, amazingly difficult.  (Like you might describe a huge bridge as "impossible-looking!")  I like questions about anime, as it is a potent contributor to English currently - so go for it.  But I fear the answer would be similar to my answer below ("there MIGHT be a specific term for this in cosplay circles...")

Comment: BTW she is in fact the fairy "Tear" right?  (Recette's buddy.)

Comment: Yeah, it's Tear. ... I'm making a fanfic and I want to describe them accurately. Arma is so hard... especially her forehead symbol! ... I was just picking different clothes that suited them, like a business suit for Tear, before I figured that I could ask about things like that here.

Comment: I don't know what the hell to call front tassels like that.  I honestly think you nailed it with bangs, front tassels, and a bun.  Maybe "long tassels on each side of her bangs."  I honestly think you could call her hairstyle "Tear-style!"  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow - Well, I'm also doing it for a portfolio, so I have to make sure it's understandable without any background knowledge, or pictures.... A bit irritating...

Comment: Really your description sounds absolutely professional to me.  I believe the answer to your "actual" question here, is there a SW, is just "no"...

Comment: [spaniel ears hairstyle](http://madameisistoilette.blogspot.it/2014/12/the-17th-century-spaniel-ears-hairstyle.html) which also includes the bun or if you prefer, chignon. Fun word, and French 17c hairstyle **hurluberlu**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the short answer is there is **no single term** for that specific hair-do.

Some hairstyles do have a more or less common name; sometimes they are named after either a fictional character or a celebrity.  For example your hairstyle here is a little bit of a **"Pippy Longstocking" hairstyle**, maybe. *{However I've just checked and Pippi has two conventional "little girl" pigtails which stick out at the **sides** - nothing like there front-tassles, really.}*

Note that **within the world of anime** there may be an exceedingly specialised term for that hair style.  (Wild guess ... "rorita-pretty style".  Or maybe "librarian cute style." Or "boygurl number 3" - or whatever.)

To know that term, you would have to watch every episode every made of [Kawaii International](http://www.nhk.or.jp/kawaii-i/), which you would have already done if you eg. make video games for a living.

FYI - [How would you describe this hair?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172643/how-would-you-describe-this-hair)  Note, your style here is not "anime hair" (anime hair is the sort of tousled-blocky style), I just refer you to that discussion.

---

By the way, funnily enough clicking to the Kawaii International site, incredibly the picture on the front is of a **somewhat similar** style (well some aspects thereof).

[image]

You can see that the term **SweetNGirly** would appear to be a catchy one this month.  (Last month it was "BoyGurl style" as I happened to mention above as an example.)

Please note that I am not suggesting your specific answer here is "SweetNGirly style". Rather,

(1) Be aware that in the anime - cosplay - Akihabara - kawaii universe, there are a tremendous number of very specific terms, which tens of millions of people in many Asian countries (and increasingly [overseas](http://asbs.jp/english/news.php?id=1170) would know.  It is possible that (unknown to us) there's a perfectly common term for that style - perhaps named for a famous character.

(2) Since you are asking this question topically, it's just possible that the front-tassle things relate to this latest fad, "SweetNGirly-stylu".

BTW I mention *Kawaii International*.  Of course, that's as old as a dictionary today, you'd be watching *Moshi Moshi Nippon*.  But that's so out there I am too old to give a link.

Comment: The hairdo in the cartoon could only be done in real life, if the model had incredibly thick hair. To have a fringe (BrEng),  two pigtails *and* enough hair at the back to roll up in a bun is pretty impossible w/o extensions; clip-ins or hairpieces. The image you posted confirms this. In the 17 c, side ringlets or curls were very much in fashion. https://books.google.it/books?id=HP1TtYHBLJsC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=side+ringlets+women+hair&source=bl&ots=_-RtSNU6y7&sig=FdjmVDW62gqpCNEqJogNRxKeKYo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BgeaVf3pD8ToUp-QmuAH&ved=0CD8Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=side%20ringlets%20women%20hair&f=false

Comment: (cont'd) which remind me of the girl's extended (left long) fringe/bangs. http://www.celebwigs.com/face-framing-hair-piece-clip-on-fringe-with-longer-bangs-available-in-2-shades/

Comment: Cool information!  Do you have a feeling on the controversial "pigtail" issue?  I think maybe they're only pigtails if at the back, or the "little girl stick out sideways" ones.

Comment: BTW I was amazed to read in that ad copy that the "Sweet-N-Girlie" style (as opposed to the now remarkably passé "Girlie" style) was **"set ablaze"** by such-and-such magazine.  Wow!  :)

Comment: heh - that's funny.  I'm LOL here

Comment: When I used to wear pigtails, or bunches, the hair was tied above my ears, they had a more "bouncy" look than the anime cartoon; however, two bunches could also be tied below the ears which meant the hair lay flat, covering the ears.